# accessing mysql field in the simpleXML through Object / Method

Tags: php, xml, arrays, simplexml

I am working on generating XML file using simpleXml...I have the following code.

```
require_once('inc.php');

    $query = $glb_connection->prepare('select * from table order by ID');
    $query->execute();
    $tree = $query->fetchAll();

    $doc = $xml->init();

    foreach($tree as $tr){
        $xml_events = $doc->addChild('entr');
        $xml_events->addAttribute('ID', $tr['ID']);
        $xml_events->addAttribute('cmp', $tr['cmp']);

       // add another child
        $xml_supervisor = $xml_events->addChild('personDetail');

        // instatiate class
        $pro = new profile();

        // passing getDetail method 
        $person = $pro->getDetail($tr['ID']);

        // it prints all the detail of the ID as expected (using it to check if return true)
        print_arr($person);

        $xml_supervisor->addAttribute('firstname', $person->lastname);
        $xml_supervisor->addAttribute('familyname', $person['lastname']);
    }   

    $file = 'example.xml';
    $xml->saveXML($doc,$file);
```

from the above code, the problem is here...I try to call the field-name from the result object person, but both way I have tried doesn't work...

```
        $xml_supervisor->addAttribute('firstname', $person->lastname);
        $xml_supervisor->addAttribute('familyname', $person['lastname']);
```

how can I call any key or value from generated result of person Object???

some one has help...

This is how the array generated when I call

```
 print_arr($person);


Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 10
            [lastname] => Sara
        )

)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ohhh, Sorry to bother you every-one, I have found the problem...I don't know what is wrong with me today, any way...

Some one might need it the exact answer some-day, so here it is....

the array is Associative-array in which if we need to call ID it should be like this..

array[0][ID]...means

this should be called like this..

```
 $xml_supervisor->addAttribute('familyname', $person[0]['lastname']);
```

That is it.